# Object creates blank render, when object is disabled render works correctly

Tags: rendering, orthographic

I have a confusing issue. I'm trying to create an orthographic render of my terrain for a heightmap. But if my terrain object is enabled for rendering, my renders are blank. If I disable it, my renders work correctly. I tested it with a cube object. With the terrain enabled, the render is blank, when I disable the terrain, the cube gets rendered. I have no idea what's going on.